# The differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\;$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning differential equations and can do the basic examples. However, how can you solve the differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\;?$$

Comment: Doesn't it look a bit like a [Bernoulli differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation)?

Comment: As an alternative to the answer by Start wearing purple, you could also use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting $y=\sqrt x\, u(x)$, the equation becomes separable:
$$\sqrt x\, u'=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\left(\frac{u}{2}-\frac1u\right).$$
Therefore, writing
$$\frac{2u du}{u^2-2}=\frac{dx}{x},$$
we get 
$$\ln\left(u^2-2\right)=\ln x+C \qquad \Longrightarrow \quad y(x)=\pm\sqrt{x(2+Cx)}.$$

Comment: we get with the method above $$y=\pm\sqrt{Cx^2+2x}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, thanks, it just took me a couple of minutes to type a complete answer.

Comment: +1 But How did you get the idea to use that substitution it's not obvious.

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Since I wanted a separable equation, I looked at the r.h.s. and tried to find a change of variables $y=f(x)u$ under which the right side becomes $F(x)G(u)$. Of course this could fail because the left side is also modified. But fortunately the modification was just of the form we would like to have.

Comment: Ah okay thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You already have nice solutions with substitutions. If one cannot come up with the right substitution, maybe this is a solution that works better:

Multiplying the differential equation with $y$ gives
$$
yy'=\frac{y^2}{x}-1,
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{2}\bigl(y^2\bigr)'=\frac{y^2}{x}-1.
$$
This is a linear and first order differential equation for $y^2$, we write it as
$$
\bigl(y^2\bigr)'-\frac{2}{x}y^2=-2
$$
The integrating factor is $1/x^2$, so
$$
\Bigl(\frac{1}{x^2}y^2\Bigr)'=-\frac{2}{x^2}.
$$
Integrating,
$$
\frac{1}{x^2}y^2=\frac{2}{x}+C,
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. We can write this as
$$
y^2=2x+Cx^2\quad \text{or}\quad y=\pm\sqrt{2x+Cx^2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac { dy }{ dx } =\frac { y }{ x } -\frac { 1 }{ y } \;$$ substitute

> $$y=xt$$

$$  \frac { dy }{ dx } =t+x\frac { dt }{ dx } \\ t+x\frac { dt }{ dx } =t-\frac { 1 }{ xt } \\ x\frac { dt }{ dx } =-\frac { 1 }{ xt } \\ \int { tdt } =\int { -\frac { d }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  } \\ \frac { { t }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } =\frac { 1 }{ x } +C\\ \frac { { y }^{ 2 } }{ { x }^{ 2 } } =\frac { 2 }{ x } +C\\ y=\pm \sqrt { 2x+{ x }^{ 2 }C } $$

Comment: Is there a factor of $2$ missing? Should it be $\pm\sqrt{2x+Cx^2}$?

Comment: @Anush,thanks ,i edited

Answer (score 1):

Multilpying the equation by $2y$ we get , $$2y\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{2y^2}{x}=-2.$$Now put , $y^2=z$. Then ,$$\frac{dz}{dx}-\frac{2z}{x}=-2.$$So , $I.F.=e^{-2\ln x}=\frac{1}{x^2}$. Then solution is $$\frac{z}{x^2}=-2\int\frac{dx}{x^2}+C$$That is $$\frac{y^2}{x^2}=\frac{2}{x}+C.$$

Comment: Thank you for another approach!